# The file that should update the software in the car does not start, why?

Tags: java, jnlp

I have a file that is run using Java, which will launch an application that updates the software in the car.
But the file does not run, it gives an error.

Updated java, reinstalled windows, nothing helps
What could be the problem?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vJHu.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUSBe.png)

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RA1B4.png)

tried all available tips

- reinstalled Java
- installed some different versions of java

I'm afraid they are too simple
Or the problem is that from my side it is not possible to solve.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0" codebase="https://tis2web.service.gm.com/tis2web/sps/download">
    <information>
        <title>SPS V. 7.8.230</title>
        <vendor>GM SPO</vendor>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions />
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" initial-heap-size="64m" max-heap-size="512m" />
        <extension name="common" version="7.8.230"
            href="https://tis2web.service.gm.com/tis2web/jnlp.extension/common.jnlp" />

        <jar href="webwindow.jar" version="1.0.8.6" />
        <jar href="jsoup-1.13.1.jar" version="1.13.1" />
        <jar href="itext-1.3.jar" version="1.0.1.6" />
        <jar href="jeval.jar" version="0.9.9" />
        <jar href="snmp.jar" version="1.4.2.6" />
        <jar href="joda-time-2.4.jar" version="2.4.6" />
        <jar href="gson-2.7.jar" version="2.7.6" />
        <jar href="commons-compress-1.5.jar" version="1.5.6" />
        <jar href="httpclient-4.5.2.jar" version="4.5.2" />
        <jar href="httpcore-4.4.4.jar" version="4.4.4" />
        <jar href="commons-logging-1.2.jar" version="1.2" />

        <jar href="sps-client.jar" main="true" version="7.8.230" />
        <jar href="sps-common.jar" version="7.8.230" />
        <jar href="techlinecache-client.jar" version="7.8.230" />

        <nativelib href="sps-startuplibs.jar" version="7.8.230" />

        
        

    </resources>
    <application-desc
        main-class="com.eoos.gm.tis2web.sps.client.ui.SPSClientController">
        <argument>https://tis2web.service.gm.com/tis2web/exectask/sps</argument>
        <argument>SlNFU1NJT05JRD1nTGlmRWNva1AyZnp1dEpDMnBHLUI0UV9ST3JLcVVIS1R6WkcwVVF2VGQ4NC1qejEyMVN2IS03ODQ3NTQ2NTsgYXV0aGVudGljYXRlZD02NDAyYzYyMzI0MmMyYTIzMzBjMzRkZjc1N2YxNjEzYzsgX2FiY2s9NDQ0Qzc5NEFCNDY3Q0UyODlDNUU4NTVCRDc5Q0UwRUR+MH5ZQUFRbmp4UmFJY1hzcG1FQVFBQVQvckJtd2dockdYc1RQSVYrNVloWjZBQWF4ckxsQzhFQ2VDMmRNbUtLa3FyMTFVZlY1dk5jb3ltWHFwNlQ0ekVnVXdXWjBKSmpzcHlYanliSWZZOTRRT0FHQlVzeDFlYzlwMmdoNENiS3MrbTJXS1dSOVZQTGVMdFJ0OGdCZnFzaDhHWm5VNDh5eWZ1d2lvYytJUW03azR5c0xKbmpDYUI4ZTNrbUdXTmN0MVg5T3NMdnJWbU5SUktXQVBmeEpOUFd4cmZuK0VrcVJFMXNQQWJNUmgxemlwVWVWNFlqbVpldzRaWmN5c0lURnBNWWJBRWpaeTZCU0ZmWE5oMUlnYkdMZkwvTnh1N09xRG80c0RRanZna2czZjBzQk9qVU10dWZtOTQrN2ptYkx0OUhya1NQbU9SSWdvcEZDOGdoSUlIZEhSUjdMcGlremdORTNha2w4ZHFKclM5Z2xPLys4NzI5czA0TWlMVHVwMk9FZ1ZWeUJFU0N0MW1Id2J6dll4YnQyVHM1aGs9fi0xfi0xfi0xOyBha19ibXNjPTU2RTMzQTFERkYzMzgxOTZENjVDRkVGRkZERDUxRjQ5fjAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMH5ZQUFRalR4UmFDNVNwNW1FQVFBQUJjd1JueEVzZ24vRmxHRktPQ052M2dGUjFTWnBkdFdMUTFPQ0JGSkJ5QWNPRHJFUGx3ODB3THc5Y2dFeVBBMnR6dDR6R1laOW4ybXRTWDdqNUZ3ZHczNkczVkxERURQZ09GR0x6cEdpOWxkR2E5dkFiOWZTaXJkbVJvdWNhVnBXT1JNdkRKcjZadkhtQnVHYmJGSGpXZTY3MEQ1ejB1SXZqNnNPZzJwbEJTKytIREVHenMzQlFKRU1vUVVZMXJjMmhxaDV2d2E5ZGpLUUNKOWRZYW03SUF6TXNCY0pyTFJ2Qnp0L0xaY290ZmdNc29McU14V3RUMTMwb2poQWxjM1JoMVNqY3dSVkdSNlg4UmROTEhEa2FEYnhEbWN1eEtVeDBvSUMzYVlXN1RCMmYvdW83ZjhxbGIrdGJGS2hCV1FzbU5VNElwcTRoNEc3bEVEaGkyZ0tQUVdFbFhycFNrTjNScUg4L0FudFVMYXFrMG5LN3c9PTsgYm1fc3Y9MEFEMkUxNjcxNjA1NjQ1MEI1NDIzNkM3MEY1RTNBRkZ+WUFBUWpUeFJhSnhUcDVtRUFRQUFrZjRSbnhIbzdjMFFuTThnbzE0akRTSTJUV2VVVHlnZmlCUWFUYXhteWxZNkFwNWRvYU5KeWxqd1p5eHJVZXhZUVVHRDkxYWFjeDAwemFLcUlIQXQ4ZGVuV2JLMzcwVUVGU0tLUDM0MndpWXdOaVRONENhZGtaNlNIRXpzUExqenhvNG1TdklPZUZEYmRvRXB4cHpkOG1Ha0VENnBkbWRLRnJlVzk0NmpNM05yc0pIdnV0T0k5WmRxa0VwMThnUTJndGxVS1NQK2tXZ1BJQjdhVnJscEJnVmRhYzdlSmtlbnJMNVAzLzFQT0ZaWnJ5VFZsZz09fjE=</argument>
        <argument>ACM2AXV2A8S2A</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: So this is a Java Web Start application. You probably know that this is an obsolete technology. It is however not quite dead and Web Start software is available so you might be in with a chance. I can't really say any more without examining the URL. Do you have the full URL to the jnlp file?

Comment: I have file jnlp.

Comment: But i don't know how i can add this file here

Comment: You could start by posting its contents as code (i.e. in code tags)

Comment: ok, posted the code in the original post

Comment: using Notepad +++ opened the file, copied the code, and published it in the original post

Comment: When I try to run that 'manually' there's a missing class. I can't advise anything other than contact the manufacturer